# Find knockout element by jquery selector

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have some elements rendered with knockout:

```
<div class="chart" data-bind="attr: {'data-chart-id': id}"></div>
```

And then I want to find jquery element by data attribute: `$("[data-chart-id='1']")`

But when I do it in the model, `data-chart-id` of the model is not assignned yet.

How to deal with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use setTimeout to wait for the binding finish or write a [custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html):

HTML:

```
<div class="chart" data-bind="customAttribute: {chartId: id}"></div>
```

JS:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.customAttribute = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
         var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor().chartId); 
         $(element).attr('chartId', value);
         // then you can write your jquery code here
    }
};
```

Comment: It was pretty good solution to write the custom binding. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("body *[data-chart-id='1']");
```

Comment: It doesn't work when I do it in the JS file. Only from the browser console